# Pictures of Black Bottom (Detroit neighborhood replaced with Lafayette Park in the 1960s)

Tags: data-request, images, historical

I am looking for pictures of [Black Bottom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Bottom,_Detroit), a Detroit neighborhood demolished and replaced with [Lafayette Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lafayette_Park,_Detroit) in the 1960s. It was the bithplace of the genre known as [Detroit blues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit_blues).

Landscapes, buildings, life scenes, people, anything.

Pictures must be reusable in Wikipedia (compatible with Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0).

Wikimedia Commons does not seem to have any:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Historic_districts_of_Detroit,_Michigan

Comment: I marked this as off-topic because I consider single pictures to be "information" and not "data". (in contrast to view here: http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/a/230/1511)

Comment: The meta question you link to precisely shows how the question above IS on-topic. By the way, I am NOT looking for a single picture, I am looking for several.